# Union & Pivot multiple tables with different values for similar records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, union

I have multiple tables with the same customer records, but each table has it's own cost currency.

Table 1:

```
User    Country     COST_USD
1         USA         10
2         USA         5
3         USA         3
```

Table 2:

```
User    Country     COST_EUR
1         USA         12
2         USA         7
3         USA         5
```

Table 3:

```
User    Country     COST_YEN
1         USA         100
2         USA         50
3         USA         30
```

What I am looking for is to Union those tables and then pivot the currencies to individual columns (or pivot then union) as follows:

```
User    Country     COST_USD    COST_EUR    COST_YEN
1         USA       10          12          100
2         USA       5           7           50
3         USA       3           3           30
```

I have tried union all and then pivot but that didn't work since I have differnt currency columns.

Comment: This isn't pivoting, it's just a `JOIN` (on `User` and `Country`). Though I would suggest fixing your design and normalising it. The above should be 1 table with [at least] 4 columns; User[ID], Country, Currency and Value. *Then* you would need a `PIVOT`, or conditional aggregation, to get the result you want; but the important thing is the design is fixed and far easier to work with. You don't, for example, need to start adding a "new table" every time there's a new currency, which makes your design scale awfully, you just add an extra row to your table.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were thinking of-

```
select user, country, MAX(COST_USD) COST_USD,MAX(COST_EUR) COST_EUR,MAX(COST_YEN ) COST_YEN 
from
(
select user, country, COST_USD, NULL AS COST_EUR, NULL AS COST_YEN from table1
union all
select user, country, NULL AS COST_USD, COST_EUR, NULL AS COST_YEN from table2
union all
select user, country, NULL AS COST_USD, NULL AS COST_EUR, COST_YEN from table3
)T
group by user, country
```

but if you have many currency columns then you ought to maybe unpivot and union all and the pivot back.

```
select user, country, currency, amount
from
(select user, country, cost_curr from tableN)U
unpivot
(amount for currency in (COST_EUR, COST_USD,COST_YEN, cost_curr))UPVT
```

The above is done for all tables and the all resulting unpivots are unioned all and the pivoted back.
As you can see this is quite tedious.

or change you design if possible.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, this is just a `JOIN`. Based on your sample data, an `INNER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT T1.[User], --USER is a reserved keyword, and should not be used for object names
       T1.Country,
       T1.COST_USD,
       T2.COST_EUR,
       T3.COST_YEN
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
     JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T1.[User] = T2.[User] --USER is a reserved keyword, and should not be used for object names
                       AND T1.Country = T2.Country
     JOIN dbo.Table3 T3 ON T1.[User] = T3.[User] --USER is a reserved keyword, and should not be used for object names
                       AND T1.Country = T3.Country;
```

Of course, I *doubt* all your table have a value for a specific user, so you likely want a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(T1.[User],T2.[User],T3.[User]) AS [User], --USER is a reserved keyword, and should not be used for object names
       COALESCE(T1.Country,T2.Country,T3.Country) AS Country,
       T1.COST_USD,
       T2.COST_EUR,
       T3.COST_YEN
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
     FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T1.[User] = T2.[User] --USER is a reserved keyword, and should not be used for object names
                       AND T1.Country = T2.Country
     FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Table3 T3 ON T3.[User] IN (T1.[User],T2.[User])--USER is a reserved keyword, and should not be used for object names
                                  AND T3.Country IN (T1.Country,T2.Country);
```

But, like I mentioned, the *real* solution is fix your design, and have a single table that looks something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (UserID int,
                            Country nvarchar(50),
                            Currency char(3),
                            Value decimal(12,0));
```

Then your data would look like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES(1,'USA','USD',10),
      (1,'USA','EUR',12),
      (1,'USA','YEN',100);
```

And finally you would get your results with conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT UserID,
       Country,
       MAX(CASE Currency WHEN 'USD' THEN Value END) AS COST_USD,
       MAX(CASE Currency WHEN 'EUR' THEN Value END) AS COST_EUR,
       MAX(CASE Currency WHEN 'YEN' THEN Value END) AS COST_YEN
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY UserID,
         Country;
```